# Are there any special challenges for functional programming in an embedded environment?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, embedded

So I'm starting to get a feel for what sets functional programming apart from imperative programming. So like any good convert I'm looking at things with the Haskell hammer and trying to imagine how my embedded programming work could be shaped as appropriate nails for that tool.

So that got me thinking about this question. Is the embedded environment a special case of general computing in the eyes of functional programming or is it just another form of the general case? Is the challenge all in the IO? My embedded work usually entails about 90 - 95% peripheral IO work and the last little bit of stuff being what algorithm work I can fit onto it and still make it back to my IO in time. Does that sort of work make a functional program unsuited to my needs?

Finally, if there are any projects to embedded Haskell projects you could suggest, that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of promising projects for bringing functional programming to the embedded programming world.

It seems like a common approach is to take advantage of the type safety and other correctness features of but to abandon heavyweight runtime like ghc. As a result of abandoning the run time, you give up features like garbage collection. Instead, embedded Haskell projects use embedded DSL languages that output real time C code.

Embedded projects using mix C, C++ and Haskell code, rather than being pure functional projects. The C code produced from the Haskell code is not idiomatic C code so collaborators on the project typically need to be familiar with Haskell syntax to participate.

Galois's Copilot project is one the mode extensively documented embedded Haskell projects.

http://corp.galois.com/blog/2010/9/22/copilot-a-dsl-for-monitoring-embedded-systems.html

Copilot uses the Atom DSL which seems popular

http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/atom-0.0.2

There is also a moderately active Google Group

https://groups.google.com/forum/#forum/fp-embedded

Comment: It is weird that functional languages could work without garbage collection. How do you deal with closures, continuations and fast lists without GC ?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: In the case of something like Atom, your Haskell program actually outputs C.  The design of the Atom library controls the kind of constructs the resulting C code can contain.  As it's designed for embedded systems, it doesn't generate code that uses dynamic memory allocation, or the like.

Comment: @Alexandre C: There's lots of work on static inference of resource usage for functional programs. This can eliminate the need for GC.

Comment: @Alexandre C: Well that's just the thing about Atom, you don't. Atom doesn't support any of that, which is one reason I wouldn't consider it at all for embedded systems programming.

Comment: @Andreas: ok, so what is the point of using a functional language if you can't use most (if not all) of its features ? It sounds a bit like having a ferrari with a lawnmoan engine.

Comment: @Alexandre C: My point exactly. I'm having problems perceiving the benefits of Haskell.Atom.

Comment: Galois seems to be marketing Haskell in embedded contexts where correctness of an embedded system monitor is at premium. 

I can imagine using Haskell in a context where I have simple 8 slave microcontroller controlling a Peltier device but then I want monitoring from the master with provable properties.

Comment: If correctness/provability are the primary concerns then maybe [CertiCoq](https://certicoq.org) might be something to consider. From the [release paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/certicoq-coqpl.pdf): »This work in progress should soon yield a compiler that is useful (for compiling Gallina programs that you have proved correct in Coq), efficient (in compilation time), optimizing (competitive with Ocaml), verified (with proofs in Coq), compatible (with C and Ocaml), and elegant.«

Answer (score 1):

Personally I found Haskell.Atom quite lacking. It's not functional programming it's an EDSL in a functional language. You are limited to the constructs of that EDSL. No higher order functions, list comprehensions and all the other things that make functional programming so succinct and enjoyable. It may be fun for exceptionally small projects (like blinking a LED) but to me it seems the code *you* write (not only the generated C-code) will grow exponentially compared to the functionality it provides.

If you want to go the functional route I suggest reading this [paper](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/ftpdir/pub/malcolm/thesis.html) by Malcolm Wallace. It's a bit dated but at least it describes in quite a detail how to do low-level I/O, IRQ-handling and so on in a pure functional language ([Gofer](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/goferarc/index.html), a Haskell-dialect).

Update: There's also a quite new [research project](http://hasp.cs.pdx.edu/) with the goal to make a functional systems programming language based on Haskell, Habit. Unfortunately it seems to exist mostly in theory.